# How to get the inner data in mongo using projection without returning the object name

Tags: mongodb, projection

I have below data in MongoDB

```
{ "data" : {
 "key1" : "value1"
 "key2" : "value2"
 .......
 "key10" : "value10"
} }
```

I am projecting the query in scala as :

`Json.obj("data" -> 1)`

in the result I get the same output as above, but I want to skip `data` object and get only the inner data, i.e.

{
"key1" : "value1"
"key2" : "value2"
.......
"key10 : "value10"
}

I know we can use individual field names in projection, but do we have any other way to achieve this without doing aggregation or any other way. Thanks

Comment: This can be easily done with aggregation using [`"$replaceWith"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zAuhSQIRH2A).

Comment: Without aggregation, I think you may need to specify each `"key"` individually in the projection like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4nimiddf8Pu).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But yeah, I wanted to check if there is any other way other than aggregation or using individual fields.

Comment: Why those constraints? $replaceWith seems like a perfect solution

Comment: It looks that your are looking for `$replaceRoot` operator (https://mongoplayground.net/p/NKnDr5rvN3p), but i don't know how to use it in scala.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved this issue by handling this in Scala...